# Shell script to input multiple files into program C

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program that waits for 'get', and then waits for multiple file inputs (either on the same line or one by one). 'quit' is then used to end input. My files reside in a folder "test_files/" in a different directory. What I want is for the script to input every file from my folder into my program.

Right now I have:

```
{ echo "get"; echo "file1.txt file2.txt ... fileN.txt quit"; } | ./program
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
echo "get" | ./program
for N in {files in folder}
do
echo "fileN.txt" | ./program
done
echo "quit" | ./program
```

Comment: You mean `for files in test_files/*; do ./program < files; done`?

Comment: Why is this tagged C? You do mean _any_ program, right?

Comment: Do you want to invoke your program multiple times, or do you just want `{ echo get; ls; echo quit; } | ./program`?

Comment: Please, don't tag this question as `C`, if you are asking for a shell script to do the work.  Edit the question and take off the tag.  Or if it's C, then show the code you have.  It's impossible to help you if you don't show the code you have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls file*.txt`; do
    echo $(basename $i) | ./program
done
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to ensure that the program is executable
then, in each execution wait for the file to be processed, which can be with
wait $!
(although I think I can make it wait for the end of the execution of ./program)
you can also give a timeout, like half a second
slee0 0.5

```
# before
chmod +x program
program get
for N in $(ls files*)
do
./program file$N
wait $!
# or
#sleep 0.5
done

./program quit

echo "END"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run your program, then feed it with `get`, a list of filenames, ended by `quit`, you need to produce all of these from your shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

folder=/some/folder/in/your/filesystem

# all the programs executed inside the parenthesis run in a
# subshell, so the whole output of this subshell is
# effectively redirected to the pipe to the program.
# the attempts shown in your attempt and the proposed solutions
# just execute the program several times and pass to it only one
# of the commands, not all in sequence.
( echo get    
  # for all files in folder
  for file in "$folder"/*
  do 
      echo "$file"
  done
  echo quit ) | ./program
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need simply join files and feed them to stdin of yor program just use:

```sh
cat *.txt | ./program
# or
cat file1.txt file2.txt ... fileN.txt | ./program
```